# Bird drink feeder -- How to make water come out automatically and stop coming out from a bottle?

Tags: pressure, water, air

I am watching a video about a DIY bird water feeder.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6EitavSRNg

In the video, three holes were punched from the plastic bottle in a triangular pattern, and then the video shows that when water comes out of the holes, the water will stop when the water level outside is the same as or over the 2 holes at the bottom, but when the water level outside is lower than all the 3 holes, water will come out.

Why does water come out when the water level in the bottle is above all 3 holes? Should there be no water coming out of the bottle? And if I put a 4th hole on the top of the bottle, water will come out, but it won't stop coming out until the outside water level is the same as inside the bottle. What is the trick there?

Comment: @fishinear Thank you for the link, it seems to answer my question, but I have some difficulty to understand it. So to reach the "equilibrium" where water stops coming out, the water level will be around 7mm below the hole. But what about the height of the hole and the size (or curvature c) of the hole? How do I determine them?

Comment: The comments to the other question link to a video using different hole sizes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVNmyBTaJ9s

Comment: @fishinear Thanks, I watched the video and understands more. I am also able to create the same scenario using a bottle with a hole too. But my question now is, in the video in the question, the bottle cap is closed and 3 holes are punched in a triangular pattern, while in the video you quote, the bottle cap is open and only 1 hole is needed. So do the 2 holes at the bottom serve the same purpose as the open lid, just for water to come out only?

Comment: _"So do the 2 holes at the bottom serve the same purpose as the open lid, just for water to come out only?"_ - correct.